# Convert List<Map<String, Object>> to List<String>

Tags: java

I have a List of Map `List<Map<String, Object>>.` I need only the values of the List of Map to be moved into `List<String>`.

Can someone please let me know how to convert?

Comment: Can you put up your working/non-working code ?

Comment: Please format your post correctly, clarify your problem and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Create a new list, loop over the list of maps, for each map add the values to your new list. Please try it yourself and post your code if you get stuck.

Comment: The values of the map `Map<String, Object>` are of type `Object`. You want to convert these *VALUES* to type `String` and store them in a list? Correct? Or is it the *KEYS* of type `String` you want to store in a separate list?

Comment: I have similar problem where I need Objects in Map to be stored in a List. I would like to know a solution using Java Streams API.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
      List<Map<String, Object>>  mapList=new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

      List<Object> list=new ArrayList<Object>();
      for(Map<String,Object> i:mapList){
          list.addAll(i.values());
      }
```

Comment: Quote OP: "... to be moved into `List<String>`".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: ByteCode's right. Quote:  I need only the values of the List of Map [i.e. the objects] to be moved into List<String>.

Comment: @W.K.S And how is ByteCode right when he moves the objects into a `List<Object>`? And btw the objects themselves *are not strings*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   List<Map<String, Object>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();       
   List<String>  listOfValue = new ArrayList<String>();       
   for(Map map: maps){ // loop through the maps
       listOfValue.addAll(map.values()); // append the values in listOfValue
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries from Google and do it functionally:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.base.Function;

// ...

final List<Map<String, Object>> list = ...;
final Function<Map<String, Object>, Collection<String>> mapToKeysFunction = new Function<Map<String, Object>, Collection<String>>() {

    @Override
    public Collection<String> apply(final Map<String, Object> map) {
        return map.keySet();
    }
};
final List<Collection<String>> listOfStringCollections = Lists.transform(list, mapToKeysFunction);
final Iterable<String> stringIterable = Iterables.concat(listOfStringCollections);
// either use string iterable here directly or convert it to List if necessary
final List<String> result = Lists.newArrayList(stringIterable);
```

now rewriting this code using static imports, it'll look like the following:

```
// store this function somewhere as public static final - it can be easily reused in the future
public static final Function<Map<String, Object>, Collection<String>> mapToKeysFunction = new Function<Map<String, Object>, Collection<String>>() {

    @Override
    public Collection<String> apply(final Map<String, Object> map) {
        return map.keySet();
    }
};

// ...

final List<Map<String, Object>> list = ...;
final List<String> result = newArrayList(concat(transform(list, mapToKeysFunction)));
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

If your object is of type List of string, i.e `List<Map<String, List<String>>>`

Then you can get flattened list of values using **stream** api of JAVA 8. Below is sample code snippet:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMap = YOUR_OBJECT

List<String> finalList = listOfMap.stream().map(map -> (List<String>) map.get(KEY))
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream()).distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if you want `List<Object>` from `List<Map<String, Object>>`, then below is code snippet:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMap = YOUR_OBJECT

List<Object> finalList = listOfMap.stream().map(map -> map.get(KEY))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please answer according to question and not create your  own scenario.

Comment: May be not related to the question. But this answer helped me in another way.

Comment: What is KEY in map.get(KEY) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

```
    List<Map<String, Object>>  mapList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map<String,Object> i:mapList){
          for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry:i.entrySet()){
                  list.add(entry.getKey());
          }
    }
```

If you want values you can do as follows

```
     List<Map<String, Object>>  mapList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map<String,Object> i:mapList){
          for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry:i.entrySet()){
                  list.add(entry.getValue().toString());
          }
    }
```

Comment: Why not let him try on his own first ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi ... to get easy karma?

Comment: Karma is a myth PS- i am from India ;)

Comment: @AnkitRustagi I figured as much---sorry about the Geek Culture misusing your native myth for something much more mundane :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listMap = (declared somewhere);
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Map<String, Object> m : listMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : m.entrySet()) {
        stringList.add(e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

class ListCheck 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        List<Map<String,Object>> newList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();


        Map<String,Object> integerMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        integerMap.put("one",new Integer(1));
        integerMap.put("two",new Integer(2));
        integerMap.put("two",new Integer(3));

        Map<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        Map<String,Object> doubleMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        doubleMap.put("one",new Double(1.0));
        doubleMap.put("two",new Double(2.0));
        doubleMap.put("two",new Double(3.0));


        newList.add(integerMap);
        newList.add(doubleMap);
        //target list to which will have all the values of the map
        List<String> targetList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        /*Code to iterate Map and add the value to the list */

        for (Map<String,Object> currentMap : newList) {
               //check for currentMap null check
                 for (Map.Entry<String,Object> curEntry:currentMap.entrySet()){ 
                    String s = (String) curEntry.getValue().toString();  //handle your case accordingly,with null check and other to stirng
                    targetList.add(s);
                 }
        }


        /*Testing the targetList */

        for (String s : targetList) {
                System.out.println(s);
         }


    }
}
```